# How to fix "App failed to update" error in Developer Portal?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a bot for Microsoft Teams using the Bot Framework SDK so I created a bot in the [Developer Portal](https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/).

I added a some commands so a command menu is generated, I saved the changes and published the bot.

However, I realized I did not identify my bot by selecting an existing bot in the dropdown. I went back to select it, but clicking Save has been giving me the red error at the top of the page.

`App failed to update (Tracking info: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx_xx Tue, 09 Aug 2022 21:39:01 GMT | Status code: 400`

[image]

I think because I haven't identified my bot, the manifest doesn't update with the commands.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please try to redo the process by deleting existing one and check if that helps?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. You want me to delete the existing bot, recreate it, and then try to select it again?

Comment: I did the above and now it saved successfully. Do you know what the issue might have been? Either way, feel free to post a solution and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Developer Portal creates a unique app ID and locks the ID for your registered Teams app. You can’t edit or provide an ID of your choice, which prevents to have duplicate app IDs for multiple apps.
In your case as you haven't selected your existing bot, the manifest didn't update with the commands, and it throws the error.
Deleting existing instances and redoing the process helps.